# Using tkinter wait_variable in two classes

Tags: python, tkinter, python-3.7

I've been trying to run a tkinter GUI that runs using classes. To switch between the classes I was using destroy blocks which were delayed by wait_variable until a button was pressed which updates the variable and runs the next class. However, when I used my wait_variable in two separate classes it broke.

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

def function1():
    wait.set(1) 
    class2(master) 
def function2():
    wait.set(1)
    class1(master)

wait = IntVar()

class class1: 
    def __init__(self, window_name): 
        button1=Button(master, text="Button1", command=function1)
        button1.place(relx=0.3, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.3, relheight=0.35, anchor=CENTER)
        window_name.wait_variable(wait)
        button1.destroy()

class class2: 
    def __init__(self, window_name):
        canvas = Canvas(master, highlightthickness=3, highlightbackground="black", bg="white")
        canvas.place(relx=0.757, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.22857, relheight=0.97, anchor=W) 
        button2=Button(master, text="Button2", command=function2) 
        button2.place(relx=0.16875, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.14286, relheight=0.11, anchor=CENTER)
        window_name.wait_variable(wait) #<-- here
        order_display_canvas.destroy()
        button2.destroy()

class1(master)

master.mainloop() #creates windows loop
```

This is the bare bones of my code so the arrangement is a bit weird (Note this will end up using more than two linked modules later). Any help appreciated.

Edit: I would implement acw1668's suggestion but eventually I want to have multiple buttons, on a single page, that each lead to different classes. Therefore it would solve the bare bones but not the generalized form.

Comment: You should not initialize `class2()` and `class1()` inside `function1()` and `function2()`.  Initialize `class2()` at the end of `__init__()` of `class1()` and vice versa.

Comment: This works with linking the two but it won't work when I implement alternative class calls for the same page. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Does not understand _"it won't work when I implement alternative class calls for the same page"_.  Can you update your question with the above case?

Comment: You can use another global variable to hold the reference of the class to be created.  Then update this variable inside button command callback and initialize the class at the end of `__init__()` function.

Comment: What does "it broke" mean? Did the program crash? Do you get an error?

Comment: Sorry, by broke I mean the wait_variable is not updated causing the elements in a class to not be destroyed.